# What method is called when user taps outside a popover

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipopover

A quickie...what (if any) method is called when the user dismisses a UIPopover by tapping outside of it? If I want something to happen at this point, where is my hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UIPopoverControllerDelegate we have delegate method called `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` Read : [Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for greater understanding about how to use it.